# $R = C ([0; 1]; R)$ is the ring of continuous functions in the closed interval [0,1] with usual sum and product operations of functions.

Tags: ring-theory

"If $R = C ([0; 1]; R)$ is the ring of continuous functions in the closed interval [0; 1] with usual sum and product operations of functions, then $f \in R$ is a divisor of zero if e only if $\{x \in [0; 1]: f (x) = 0\}$ contains an open range."

This question was left as an example in my abstract algebra class. I'm trying to resolve this, but I can't find that gap open.

Comment: You should distinguish between $R$ and $\mathbb R$, by typing \mathbb R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what "that gap open" means. But the problem is easy.

When $f\in R$ is a divisor of zero then there is a $g\neq0$ in $R$ with $f(x) g(x)\equiv0$ $(0\leq x\leq1)$. There is a $c\in[0,1]$ with $g(c)\ne0$. As $g$ is continuous there is a neighborhood $U$ of $c$ such that $\ldots$

When $f^{-1}(0)$ contains an open range there is an interval $\>]a,b[\>\subset[0,1]$ such that $f(x)\equiv0$ on $\>]a,b[\>$. We can then find a $g\in R$, $\>g(x)\neq0$ such that $\ldots$